# Unable to login after first installing wordpress website - due to Theme my login plugin auto redirection

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I got 'Theme My Login' and 'Groups' plugins working great together on my localhost (for a members only area).

Now I've uploaded the website to the online server.

Normally when I first upload a wordpress site from my localhost, I immediately log-in and go to settings / Permalinks, and save (This fixes the problems with interior pages displaying).

However, I can't do this, because I can't login.  The 'Theme My Login' plugin forces the normal /wp-login/ to go to this location:

http://www.brightongate.com.au/login/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brightongate.com.au%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Which of course is considered an interior page, so I can't access it.

I've tried: http://www.brightongate.com.au/wp-admin/ and http://www.brightongate.com.au/wp-login/ and they both go to a 404 page.

To see what should happen with a website that has this working correctly, try logging into http://www.12thcaulfield.asn.au, and you will be transferred to this URL:

http://www.12thcaulfield.asn.au/login/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.12thcaulfield.asn.au%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Outside of going back to my localhost version of the website and disabling the two plugins, and then re-uploading everything.. can anyone come up with a work-around to just get me logged in first?

Or is there a tricky way to update the permalinks settings and flush rewrite rules without being logged in?

(And if I have to disable the plugins on my localhost version.. what do I have to re-upload.. just all the WordPress files?  Or do I have to recreate the database too?)

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to deactivate your plugins ( `Theme My Login` and `Groups`). Go to `File manager` or `FTP` of your server, and change the folder names of that plugins by adding some suffix to folder names. Rename like:

`{your-website-folder}/wp-content/plugins/{plugin-name}` to `{your-website-folder}/wp-content/plugins/{plugin-name-1}`

It will disabled your plugins. Also, if it don't help, change your `.htaccess` file to default wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This steps will allow you to log in.

Comment: You beauty, mate!  Thanks so much!!!  Worked like a charm.  I've re-named the plugin folder back to the original and that is working also.  You saved me hours of work and aggravation!  Cheers!

Comment: Glad to be helpful